# Slick Java Library - update method

Tags: slick2d

Ok I am developing a game and I am trying to work out why the slick update method isn't working, basically in the tutorial I was watching it worked but on mine it doesn't. I asked on the you tube tutorials video and no one knew why this happened. So any help would be appreciated. here is my code:

`package phex.launcher;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;
import org.lwjgl.*;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.Image;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.BasicGameState;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;


public class Phex extends BasicGameState{

    public static int screen;
    private Image tweet;
    private Image logo;
    private Image base;
    private Graphics g;
    private GameContainer gc;

    public Phex() throws SlickException
    {
        new LoginButton();
        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800, 650));
            Display.setTitle("Phex Launcher");
            Display.setResizable(true);
            Display.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Display.destroy();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        init(gc, null);


        //Initialisation code(OpenGL)
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity(); // Resets any previous projection matrices
        glOrtho(0, 800, 650, 0, 1, -1);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        while(!Display.isCloseRequested())
        {
            //render
            render(gc, null, g);
            update(gc, null, 0);
        }
        Display.destroy();

    }   

    public static void main(String args[]) throws SlickException
    {
        new Phex();
    }
    public void init(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game)
            throws SlickException {
        tweet = new Image("img/twitter-logo.png");
        logo = new Image("img/logo.png");
        base =  new Image("img/base-for-login.png");


    }
    public void render(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game, Graphics g)
            throws SlickException {
        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE))
        {
            Display.destroy();
            System.exit(0);
        }

        base.draw(0,0);
        logo.draw(50, 5);
        tweet.draw(200, 5);

        //screen renderer
        screen = 0;
        if(screen == 0)
        {

        }
        if(screen == 1)
        {

        }



        Display.update();
        Display.sync(60);

    }
    public void update(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game, int delta)throws SlickException {
        int posx = Mouse.getX();
        int posy = Mouse.getY();

        if((posx>50 && posx<150)&&(posy>5 && posy<100))
        {
            System.out.println("in area");
            if(Mouse.isButtonDown(0))
            {
                Display.destroy();

            }
        }

    }
    @Override
    public int getID() {
        return 0;
    }
}`

Comment: can you post link to that video tutorial ?

Answer (score 1):

Sat reading this over breakfast (ie not in too much depth!) it looks like you're overriding `BasicGameState`, and not `StateBasedGame`. I can't see any evidence of the latter anywhere?

Comment: thanks for an answer! I just don't understand what you mean xD

Comment: A `StateBasedGame` runs `BasicGameStates`, and will call the state's update loop. As far as I can see, you're not actually creating a game to run your state.

Comment: So I need another class file that runs my BasicGameState?

Comment: Yep - I think you might have missed a step in the tutorial somewhere!

Comment: Thanks so much! last question after I have made the file above how do I make so I don't to redo too much work?

Comment: Most of your `BasicGameState` should be fine to keep I would *expect* you to have a very small class with a `static main` method, that would create and start an instance of your `StateBasedGame`, and that instance would create an instance of your `BasicGameState` and set it as the active state for that game.

Comment: Thank you so much! if I need halp I will recomment but for now its fixed! xD

Comment: If you still read this, I fixed up another class(Main) and added everything so it mostly works, except now I when I drag the window it goes black and the update method doesn't work. any solution would be much appreciated xD